# How to position an object in 3D space using cameras

Tags: opencv, arduino

Is it possible to use a couple of webcams (or any camera for that matter) to get the x, y and z co-ordinates of an object and then track them perhaps using [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) as it moves around a room.

I'm thinking of it in relation to localising and then controling an [RC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-controlled_model) helicopter.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Kinect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect)?

Comment: @GregHewgill I am also at first thought about a kinect *([here's openKinect lib](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page))*. But as I understand now — the kinect is a whole separate device, so you can't just work e.g. with a multiple WEB-cameras. Many peoples have a WEB-cameras and these are cheap, but I know no of people who even have a kinect (tbh I don't even know ones who have XBox). So, using a kinect is severely limits a use of an application with a comparison to just a cameras.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You need to detect points on both images simultaneously and then match the pairs that correspond to the same point in the scene. This way you will have the same point represented by different coordinate spaces (camera 1 and camera 2).

You can start [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Answer (score 1):

If using depth sensor is acceptable then you can take a look at how **[ReconstructMe](http://reconstructme.net)** does it. Otherwise take a look at **[this](http://www.google.rs/search?q=3d%202d%20camera%20model%20reconstruction)** google search.